# How has mining evolved since the start of Bitcoin?

Tags: mining-theory, hashpower, history

Can someone post a detailed description on how mining has evolved since the introduction of Bitcoin all the way till today? I mean quantity of miners, hardware used, profits made, ROI etc. I guess there has been a huge change/shift in the way mining is done over time. Is it more or less on an industrial level today due to the enormous network speed growth and a neccesity of an ASIC hardware?